How to properly implement a navigation sidebar menu in WPF with MVVM (+ figuring out a proper way to change views in the application)?
I'd like to apologise in case if anybody might find the title confusing, the problem I had described here turned out more complex than I thought and I had trouble summing it up in the title.
Basically I have an application with a main screen, which consists of a main empty screen, on which user can display other views and a side navigation panel on the side. However when I open a different view, which is being displayed on a main screen part, it also happens to cover expanded part of the navigation panel. The reasons for why it's happening are quite obvious.
In order to fix that I decided to split navigation panel and main screen into two separate views in order to make it easier to manipulate the hierarchy of views, so that navigation panel always stays on top, above all other displayed views. To my disappointment it seems that such option doesn't exist, so I came up with another idea - switch the active view upon pressing "open menu" button and change it back into the curreent one upon pressing it again.
This is how the view with side navigation panel looks like now:
<UserControl x:Class="ApkaJezykowa.MVVM.View.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ApkaJezykowa"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ApkaJezykowa.MVVM.ViewModel"
        xmlns:view="clr-namespace:ApkaJezykowa.MVVM.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="Transparent">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Border Background="Transparent">
        <Grid>
            <Grid>

                <Grid x:Name="nav_pnl" Width="80" Background=" #484848" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ZIndex="4">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="st_pln">
                        <Grid Height="80">
                            <TextBlock
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Margin="85,0,0,0"
                                    Text="Menu"
                                    FontSize="22"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Style="{StaticResource Font_Style}">
                                <TextBlock.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"
                                                          ShadowDepth="1"
                                                          Direction="-90"
                                                          Color="White"/>
                                </TextBlock.Effect>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="tg_btn"
                                              Height="60"
                                              Width="60"
                                              BorderThickness="0"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                              Style="{StaticResource tb_style}" Unchecked="tg_btn_Unchecked" Checked="tg_btn_Checked">
                                <ToggleButton.Background>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/ApkaJezykowa;component/Images/menu.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                                </ToggleButton.Background>
                                <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                                        
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard x:Name="HideStackPanel">
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="nav_pnl"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                        From="260" To="80"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.1"></DoubleAnimation>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard x:Name="ShowStackPanel">
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="nav_pnl"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                        From="80" To="260"
                                                        Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                    ></DoubleAnimation>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                </ToggleButton.Triggers>
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </Grid>
                        <ListView x:Name="LV" Background="#484848" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" BorderThickness="0" Canvas.ZIndex="3">
                            <--!just a list of options-->
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="img_bg" Margin="80,0,0,0" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="BG_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <view:MainScreenView Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
            </Grid>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding MainView}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>

</UserControl>

EDIT: And its ViewModel:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ApkaJezykowa.Main;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ApkaJezykowa.Commands;
using ApkaJezykowa.MVVM.Model;
using System.Threading;
using ApkaJezykowa.Repositories;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Timers;

namespace ApkaJezykowa.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private BaseViewModel _selectedViewModel;
        private BaseViewModel _mainView;


        public BaseViewModel SelectedViewModel
        {
            get { return _selectedViewModel; }
            set { _selectedViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel));

            }
        }
    public BaseViewModel MainView
    {
      get { return _mainView; }
      set
      {
        _mainView = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainView));

      }
    }
    public ICommand UpdateViewCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand UpdateMainViewCommand { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            UpdateViewCommand = new UpdateViewCommand(this);
            UpdateMainViewCommand = new UpdateMainViewCommand(this);
        }


  }
}
//some unecessary code had been removed for better readability

But then I faced flaws of my current design. Each view's ViewModel has its own UpdateViewCommand, which has its own triggers, which decide which view should be displayed next.
An example for The Navigation Panel:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ApkaJezykowa.MVVM.ViewModel;

namespace ApkaJezykowa.Commands
{
    internal class UpdateViewCommand : ICommand
    {
        private MainViewModel viewModel;

        public UpdateViewCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)
        {
            this.viewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if(parameter.ToString() == "Lessons")
            {
                viewModel.SelectedViewModel = new LessonsViewModel();
            }
            if (parameter.ToString() == "Dictionary")
            {
                viewModel.SelectedViewModel = new DictionaryViewModel();
            }
            if (parameter.ToString() == "Info")
            {
              viewModel.SelectedViewModel = new InfoViewModel();
            }
            if (parameter.ToString() == "Settings")
            {
              viewModel.SelectedViewModel = new SettingsViewModel();
            }
            if(parameter.ToString() == "Editor")
            {
              viewModel.SelectedViewModel = new LessonEditorViewModel();
            }
        }
    }
}

...and I have like two dozens of those. Changing views designed that way essentially prevent me from setting up this solution, because navigation panel would essentially need to know which ViewModel is currently active.
So, well, currently I see two-three ways of solving this whole mess:

Either figuring out how to manipulate hierarchy of ViewModels and make the navigation always selected via some parameter (which I have no bloody idea how to achieve),
Or completely rewrite Update View Command system to something much more flexible, which would also allow me implementing the idea with dynamically selected viewmodels and overall make the whole application code less messy (which I also have no clue how to implement),
A complete redesign of the whole side navigation panel, since I presume current design might be flawed aswell.

I hope the explanation of my problem was clear enough to be understood. As always, thanks in advance for any attempts, succesful or not, in helping me solving this.

I strongly suspect that you are confusing ViewModel with UI code extracted from Code Behind.
The function of ViewModel in WPF (for all XAML platforms) is to reflect Model in its properties. ViewModel should not track views, somehow switch them, manage them in any other way.
In theory, you should have some Model changing its states depending on ViewModel requests. These Model states should be reflected in the ViewModel property (or properties). View, tracking these properties, will automatically update, including replacing views in the Window region (or regions).
As for your implementation specifically, if you do not take into account the conceptual error described by me above, then you need to use the standard implementation command. For example, you can take it from here:  An example of my implementation of base classes: BaseInpc, RelayCommand, RelayCommandAsync, RelayCommand<T>, RelayCommandAsync<T>.
And implement a separate "Navigator" class at the View level, which will be initialized in App.
using Simplified;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Core2024.SO
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(ViewModelTypes))]
    public class SimpleNavigator : BaseInpc
    {
        public Dictionary<string, Type> ViewModelTypes { get; } = [];
        private object? _currentViewModel;
        private RelayCommand<string>? _navigateCommand;

        public object? CurrentViewModel { get => _currentViewModel; private set => Set(ref _currentViewModel, value); }

        public RelayCommand NavigateCommand => _navigateCommand
            ??= new RelayCommand<string>
            (
                name =>
                {
                    Type viewModelType = ViewModelTypes[name];

                    var ctor = viewModelType.GetConstructor([]);
                    CurrentViewModel = ctor!.Invoke([]);
                },
                ViewModelTypes.ContainsKey
            );
    }
}

<Application --------------------
             --------------------
             Startup="OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <so:SimpleNavigator x:Key="navigator"/>

        private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            SimpleNavigator navigator =(SimpleNavigator) FindResource(nameof(navigator));
            navigator.ViewModelTypes["Lessons"] = typeof(LessonsViewModel);
            navigator.ViewModelTypes["Dictionary"] = typeof(DictionaryViewModel);
            navigator.ViewModelTypes["Info"] = typeof(InfoViewModel);
        }

Use:
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel,
                                  Source{StaticResource navigator}}"
                Panel.ZIndex="1"/>

In any level View:

    <Button Command="{Binding NavigateCommand,
                              Source{StaticResource navigator}}"
            CommandParameter="ViewModel key"/>

And initialization can be done in XAML:
    <Application.Resources>
        <so:SimpleNavigator x:Key="navigator">
            <x:Type TypeName="vm:LessonsViewModel" x:Key="Lessons"/>
            <x:Type TypeName="vm:DictionaryViewModel" x:Key="Dictionary"/>
            <x:Type TypeName="vm:InfoViewModel" x:Key="Info"/>
        </so:SimpleNavigator>

P.S.

UpdateViewCommand : ICommand

    internal class UpdateViewCommand : ICommand
    {
        private MainViewModel viewModel;

        public UpdateViewCommand(MainViewModel viewModel)

This is not directly related to your question, creating a new command class "for every sneeze" is the wrong approach. It is not correct not only for WPF, but for Csharp in general. It is accepted to create such a general implementation of commands to which you can pass delegates of the necessary methods for Execute and CanExecute. You can also see an example of such use of commands in my navigator class.

Not sure if I understood you right, but I simply did not post my ViewModel code (I initially thought mentioning MVVM in the title would make it clear enough), though on the second though I am going to edit my question now and include it in order to provide the greater insight into the construction of my code. I do also use RelayCommand already.
That being said, I am going to take a closer look into the code provided. Seems like it might be exactly what I need.

@kc99
I have supplemented my answer with a small clarification on your implementation of commands.

thank you, thought that was the consensus of the whole introduction into the problem - I am aware this design is flawed and changing it is the most reasonable solution to the sea of technical issues the previous implementation amassed (as I pointed out in solution no.2).
I wonder though if I should not share some more bits of my code, in case if it turns out more of my implementations are flawed.
